# how to navigate to a page given from the user

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular2-routing

I'm building a new app and want to add functionality to the home screen.
The user will enter a value and I will take him to the page,

For example, insert value 1 will go to page 1 and so on...

Comment: Dont do that. have arrow buttons for next (>) and previous (<) page and let the user go to page 199 by typing in the url manually. What you need is a paginator

Comment: @Adelin you're right But for example if I divide the pages according to the age of the user so I want that 50 year old user will see a different page from the age 5 so I need to add a function.

Comment: Do the pages be hard-coded? or Do they have a fixed template with data(like json)?

Comment: @HyuckKang They have a fixed template with data. not json but simple text. Thank you!

Comment: Then, you don't need to create several pages. Create just one template page and when you call the page, pass the page number and data to the page.

Comment: @HyuckKang do you have an example? I am not sure I understand..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use modal, just change code the below properly.

**TemplatePage.ts**

```
// skip import
@IonicPage(//skip)
@Component(//skip)
export class TemplatePage{
  pageNumber:number;
  data:string;

  constructor(
    private navParams:NavParams
  ){
    this.data = this.navParams.get('data')
    this.pageNumber = this.navParams.get('pageNumber')
  }
}
```

**TemplatePage.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <p>page {{pageNumber}}</p>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  {{data}}
</ion-content>
```

**HomePage.ts**

```
// skip import
@IonicPage(//skip)
@Component(//skip)
export class HomePage{
  constructor(
    private modalCtrl:ModalController
  ){}

  public openPage(pageNumber:number, data:string){
    this.modalCtrl.create('TemplatePage',{pageNumber:pageNumber,data:data}).present()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ModalController is like NavController?

Comment: Actually, it's different. Compare to webpage, opening modal via [ModalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController)  is a sort of **opening popup** but navigating page via [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) is  similar to "going to new page via `<a>` tags."

Comment: So what I have in the modal that Template page is using? thanks @ Hyuck Kang

Comment: Yes, you can get what you described the above